# Backticks returns filename with spaces and surrounding command fails

Tags: macos, shell, backticks

I am trying to do something like "copy the newest file in a directory." I have come up the following command simple command using backticks, which works fine for filenames without embedded white space:

```
cp -rp `ls -1d searchstring | head -1` destination
```

As you can see this should work fine when the returned file has no space within it. However, this will obviously not work when there is such a space.

I need either a way to handle the output of the backticks, or some alternate approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can treat the result of the command substitution as a single word by adding double quotes around it:

```
cp -rp "`ls -t searchstring | head -n 1`" destination
```

The double quotes are not needed when assigning to a variable. `` a=`uptime` `` is equivalent to `` a="`uptime`" ``.

Comment: I thought I had tried that. But it does work, so I probably make some mistake in trying.